# Haskell Bad Interface File

Tags: haskell

I am trying to take my Haskell project and split it apart into a library and a set of executables that depend on the library. When I try to compile now I get the following error:

```
src/Main.hs:23:0:
    Bad interface file: /Users/<MyHomeDir>/.cabal/lib/Core-0.0.1/ghc-6.12.1/<MyModule>.hi
        mismatched interface file ways (wanted "", got "p")
```

I believe that the p might be the p flag related to packages for ghc. Is this correct? Do I need to add more configuration options somewhere to my cabal file to support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's saying it found a profiling build, but you're building `Main.hs` without profiling enabled. Quick fixes:

- enable profiling in the build for `Main.hs`
- build and install `<MyModule>` with profiling enabled

Either way, that will begin with a command that resembles

```
$ runghc Setup.hs configure --enable-library-profiling
```

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem when compiling executables with dynamic linking.

I compiled a library and executable by invoking `cabal install --ghc-option=-dynamic pkg`.

The executable was built with dynamic linking but the library part was unusable.

I assume that using the `--ghc-option=-dynamic` option caused the static version of the library was built with dynamic linking also.

Since Cabal-1.14 I can use the `--enable-executable-dynamic` option which works correctly.